# request.getParameter returning null values in chrome

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, google-chrome, struts

In my jsp page i am having two submit buttons. Code snippet is:

```
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="abc" onclick="return formCheck3(this)"/>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="xyz" onclick="return formCheck3(this)"/>
```

In formCheck3, in javascript, i am validating whether dropdown is selected and then submitting the form.In my method in action class i am having:

```
String button=request.getParameter("btnSubmit");
if(button.equals("abc")){
//certain code here
}else if(button.equals("xyz")){
//certain code here
}
```

**This is working fine in IE and mozilla but in chrome i am getting the button value as null.**
Can anyone suggest me a way around?

Comment: In my jsp i am doing is : <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Button">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Button">                  while in my action class simply i am doing like:  if (request.getParameter("update") != null) {
        

    } else if (request.getParameter("delete") != null) {
          
    } this request.getParameter is giving null value in chrome while is working in other browsers.

Comment: Your `formCheck3()` is suspicious. Are you performing `form.submit()` therin instead of returning `true/false` or what?

Comment: My javascript code:          function formCheck3(formobj)
 {
var e = document.getElementById("fiscalYear");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
//if you need text to be compared then use
var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
if(strUser==0) //for text use if(strUser1=="Select")
{
alert("Please select an year");
return false;
}else{
 window.document.forms[2].action = '${urlHlPrincipalReport1}';
    window.document.forms[2].submit();
}
return true;
 }

Comment: @BalusC: I am doing form.submit() from my javascript and returning true after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am doing form.submit() from my javascript and returning true after that*

This is not right. Returning `true` would continue the invoking element's default action, which is in case of `<input type="submit">` submitting the parent `<form>` element, which is right, but if you already submit the form beforehand, you're in essence completely overriding the element's default action.

Remove the `form.submit()` call in your JS. Let the `<input type="submit">` do its default job. This way its parameter name/value will also appear in the request parameter map. In your JS, you should control the submission by only returning either `true` or `false`.